# Where are the documents from the Documents tab in Lightning?

Tags: lightning, document, files

Our org has switched to Lightning recently and, as expected, there is no Documents tab.

From what I've read the equivalent to Documents in LEX is Files.

I would like to know where are the actual documents (not the tab, but the .pdf, etc) that were previously on the Documents tab, since I don't see them on the Files tab.Are they kept somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Documents are not available in Lightning Experience. You need to switch back to Classic to access them.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_gaps_limitations_files_and_content.htm&type=0

There is an idea you can upvote here:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E3ZTQA0

Comment: This means the content of Documents can only be seen in Classic? So I'll have to upload all the documents I have to  Files... SAD!

Answer (score 0):

As Salesforce Lightning does not support the Documents. We can alternatively use this 'Astrea Lightning Documents' appexchange to view/Delete the Documents in Lightning

Here is the Link :https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FvMvTUAV